# Compare between 2 lists or percentages and add not exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of data that I compare, specifically Column Percentages in a table and I have another list of the percentages that should be used in the Data worksheet, However, I want to make a loop through the percentages in column percentages in the table and compare them with the already existing ones in data and if it does not exist then add it by add a cell above the bottom and stick the new one(found) above.

So In my code, I passed the values from column Percentage to an array and reserved the values.
and then made another loop in array 2 that represents the list of the percentages and then got stuck where.
if not exist then insert a cell and add missed one.

```
Public Sub uniquePercent()
    Dim ival As Long
    'find the bottom of the perc list
    ival = Data.Cells.Find("End of List", searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
    Dim Srng As Range, Tablex As ListObject
    Set Tablex = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set Srng = Tablex.ListColumns("Percentage").DataBodyRange
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Lrow = Sheets("Data").Range("K" & Data.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' the list of the existed percentage
    Dim Orng As Range
    Set Orng = Sheets("Data").Range("K5:K" & Lrow) ' the range of where the list is
    Dim ar1, ar2, ar1X
    ar1 = Srng.Value ' pass percent column from the table to array
    ar2 = Orng.Value 'pass the range of the exit percent
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' loop in ar1(table)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar1)
        dict(ar1(i, 1)) = vbNullString 'not sure if that correct?
    Next i
    ar1X = dict.Keys
    dict.RemoveAll
    'loop in ar2(the exsit list)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar2)
        If Not dict.Exists(ar2, i) Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(ival, "K").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please feel free to take the time to properly indent your code.  If you don't know how to do this then please download the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and use the  code indenter.